# How to encode Int as an optional using NSCoding

Tags: xcode, swift, option-type

I am trying to declare two properties as optionals in a custom class - a String and an Int.

I'm doing this in MyClass:

```
var myString: String?
var myInt: Int?
```

I can decode them ok as follows:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  myString = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("MyString") as? String
  myInt = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("MyInt")
}
```

But encoding them gives an error on the Int line:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
  aCoder.encodeInteger(myInt, forKey: "MyInt")
  aCoder.encodeObject(myString, forKey: "MyString")
}
```

The error only disappears when XCode prompts me to unwrap the Int as follows:

```
  aCoder.encodeInteger(myInt!, forKey: "MyInt")
```

But that obviously results in a crash. So my question is, how can I get the Int to be treated as an optional like the String is? What am I missing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If it can be optional, you will have to use `encodeObject` for it, too.

You are using an Objective-C framework and Objective-C allows `nil` only for objects (class/reference types). An integer cannot be `nil` in Objective-C.

However, if you use `encodeObject`, Swift will automatically convert your `Int` to `NSNumber`, which can be `nil`.

Another option is to skip the value entirely:

```
if let myIntValue = myInt {
    aCoder.encodeInteger(myIntValue, forKey: "MyInt")
}
```

and use `containsValueForKey(_:)` when decoding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation Sulthan. I am now using myInt = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("MyInt") as? Int and aCoder.encodeObject(myInt, forKey: "MyInt") and it works fine.